# How to print the group ID

Tags: twig, drupal-8

I've installed the [group module](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) on Drupal 8 :

If I add the code `{{ group.id }}` in the `twig` of the group, it doesn't display the ID. 
How to print the group ID in `twig` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group ID will be a `FieldItemList` object and cannot be printed directly. As such, you will need to use `{{ group.id.value }}`. Similar to [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/182803/82623).

The fact that you did not report a Twig error, suggests to me that the change was not reflected on the frontend website. Try clearing your cache. You may want to read [Debugging Twig Templates](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates).

Comment: Thank you, it works. I have another question. How to print the ID of the parent group in the TWIG of a node ? In the TWIG of a node associated with a group, the following code does not work `{{ node.entity.group.id.value }}`